# ¿Es posible incluir parámetros en un texto almacenado en Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Debo enviar mails a distintos usuarios con distintos mensajes dependiendo de parametros especificos. Actualmente tengo el texto a enviar, parametrizados en duro, es decir de esta forma como ejemplo:

```
$nombre  = $usuario->__GET('Nombre');
$email = $usuario->__GET('Email');  
$informacion= $reportes->__GET('Reporte');  
$texto = "Estimado ".$nombre.", este correo es para informarle qué ".$informacion.";

enviar_mail($nombre ,$email, $texto );
```

Lo que deseo es que el texto no esté escrito en el código si no que en la base  de datos con los mismos parámetros (ya que son muchos distintos y van variando con el tiempo) para poder tener este tipo de script:

```
$nombre = $usuario->__GET('Nombre');
$email = $usuario->__GET('Email ');  
$informacion = $reportes->__GET('Reporte');  
$texto = $reportes->__GET('Texto'); 

enviar_mail($nombre ,$email, $texto );
```

Pero el texto que aparece en el parámetro `$texto` aparece con los parámetros como una cadena de caracteres.

```
"Estimado ".$nombre.", este correo es para informarle qué ".$informacion.";
```

He intentado almacenarlo en la base de datos de las siguientes formas:

- "Estimado ".$nombre.", este correo es para informarle qué
  ".$informacion."
- Estimado ".$nombre.", este correo es para informarle
  qué ".$informacion.
- Estimado $nombre, este correo es para
  informarle qué $informacion

No se si no se puede o estoy muy perdido en la forma de hacer esto.

Saludos

Comment: Que? como tienes diseñada tu base de datos? tus tablas... podrias mostrarlas.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la tabla tiene dos campos ID, que es un int y  el campo texto que es un varchar

Comment: Si te entiendo bien lo que quieres es que en la variable `$texto` se te remplaze el valor con el `$nombre` e `$informacion` que tienes previamente guardado en dichas variables

Comment: si es posible, ahora como.. hay infinidades de soluciones la idea es guardar en DB el texto y luego haces un remplazo de la palabra

Comment: @Juanmhs exactactamente es lo que necesito

Comment: Hola. Es típico hacer plantillas de la forma "texto ... %variable1 ... más texto ... %variable2 ... etc" y luego de leer la base de datos aplicar una función de reemplazo de **comodines** o lugares de emplazamiento que usa el mecanismo: reemplazar( array_nombres_de_comodines, array_valores_de_sustitución, plantilla) todos los lenguajes tienen al menos una función de sustitución y, adicionalmente puedes sofisticar con paradigmas gramaticales (y de género) para preprocesar las variables antes de aplicar el reemplazo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion que necesitas para lograr eso es `eval`, te coloco un ejemplo:

```php
//$nombre = $usuario->__GET('Nombre');
$nombre = "Eduardo";

//$email = $usuario->__GET('Email ');

//$informacion = $reportes->__GET('Reporte');
$informacion = "INFO";

//$texto = $reportes->__GET('Texto'); 
$texto= 'Estimado $nombre, este correo es para informarle qué $informacion';

eval("\$texto = \"$texto\";");
echo $texto;

//enviar_mail($nombre ,$email, $texto );
```

Comment: No conocía este constructor. Recién leí en el manual de PHP que no es muy aconsejado. No obstante funciona para lo que necesito y responde a mi pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Create una estructura para tus parámetros y los almacenas en la base de datos, por ejemplo, digamos que usas la siguiente estructura para identificar el parámetro nombre `|param:nombre|`, entonces guardas en la base de datos un texto así: `'Hola |param:nombre|, ¿te acuerdas de mi?'`.

Cuando recuperes el texto desde la base de datos, reemplazas la estructura con el valor correspondiente, como estas usando PHP entonces lo haces con la función [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php).

Te haces una función así:

```
function reemplazar_parametro_en_texto($nombre_parametro, $valor, $texto) {
    $parametro = '|param:'. $nombre_parametro .'|';
    return str_replace($parametro, $valor, $texto);
}
```

entonces la invocas así:

```
$texto = 'Hola |param:nombre|, ¿te acuerdas de mi?';
$texto = reemplazar_parametro_en_texto('nombre', 'Oscar', $texto);
// Te devolvería: 'Hola Oscar, ¿te acuerdas de mi?'
```

Más información

- [Información sobre str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Gracias Oscar, me parece que también es una buena opción aunque eval() es mas elegante. De todas formas evaluaré ambas opciones.